# how to pass parameters from views to model

Tags: codeigniter

i have a id from my view

code in my view

```
$jcid=$row->id;
```

and i have passed to my model as

```
        function getall12()
        {

           $id = $this->input->get('$jcid');
           $this->db->select();  
           $this->db->from('jobs');  
           $this->db->where('job_cat =','$id');  
           $query4=$this->db->get();
           return $query4->result();   
           return $query4->num_rows();

        }
```

is this the right way to do so

then how should i load this to my controller and back to my view

Thanks in advance.

amit

Comment: I see several mistakes here. `this->input->get('key')` returns `$_GET['key']`. and `'$id'` would not be parsed by PHP. use double quotes `""` or remove those single one `''`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong, MVC works Controller<-->Model-->view so you have tou pass data from controller to model then to the view.
If you need to pass a value you first need to get it in your controller then pass it to the model.

For example in you view (in a form?) you have to do something like:

```
echo form_open('your_controller');
<input type="text" name="jcid" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
echo form_close();
```

and retrive the value in your controller with:

```
$jcid = $this->input->get('jcid');
```

and now pass it to the model:

```
$result = $this->your_model->getall12($jcid);
```

and in your model:

```
function getall12($id)
        {


           $this->db->select();  
           $this->db->from('jobs');  
           $this->db->where('job_cat =','$id');  
           $query4=$this->db->get();
           return $query4->result();   
           return $query4->num_rows();

        }
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Models are not between Controllers and Views. `Model<-->Controller-->view` is better to indicate the relations. [CI Flow Chart](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html).

Comment: $result = $this->your_model->getall12($jcid); this should be in my model or in controller ..

Comment: $result = $this->your_model->getall12($jcid); it will be in your controller. Firstly you will load model $this->load->model('model_name','',true); I think you should go to here and study controller model and views .http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not do on controller

```
$data['jcid']=$row->id;
```

But of course do a foreach loop

Then you have in conttroller and just pass to view

Answer (score 0):

Christian Giupponi is write about everything. I just want to add there is another way of passing values between view and controller by using URI like this.

in your view:

```
echo form_open('/controller/method/id');
```

OR it also works with anchor:

```
echo anchor('/controller/method/id', 'Save ID');
```

and then in your controller:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: i a not using any form over their just simply i want that row id to match with other table with foregin key

Comment: That's why I said it also works with anchor in case u are not using forms.You have to have some kind of a button to perform the query.

Comment: thanks it helped me ..but i doesn't want it to anchor i want its id to map with other table and fetch its row id and display the num of rows in it eg like in job category's accounting(0) in place of zero it should take from table .. and update it to 1 if rows are present.

Comment: OHHH, If i understood right, what you are looking is count() functions. So once you pull your records from database and they are stored in a variable all you have to do in your view file is `<h1> Accounting(<?php echo count($variable); ?>)</h1>`. Let me know if you need more help with that.

Comment: no just i want to pass a variable from view which gets from other table

Comment: I see that I don't understand exactly what you want to do. You say you want to pass variable from view. I'm guessing you want to pass it to controller and then do something with it there. How are your trying to do that? Is it when someone clicks a button or should it be automatically when view loads? Something has to trigger the functions. Let me know. If I understand what exactly you are trying to do I might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using this method to get it done:

1. View Code

   ```
   function detail(id)
   {
   jConfirm("Check Detail?","Confirm",function(r){
      if(r)
          {
              $.post("<?php echo site_url('info/detail'); ?>",
               {
                   id      : id

               },function(data){
                 alert(data);                
               });
          }
   });
   }
   ```
2. Controller Code

   ```
   public function detail()
   {
   $this->load->model('your_model_name');
   $jcid = $this->input->post('id);
   $result = $this->your_model_name->getall12($jcid);
   echo $result;
   }
   ```
3. View Code

   ```
   function getall12($id)
   {


      $this->db->select();  
      $this->db->from('jobs');  
      $this->db->where('job_cat =','$id');  
      $query4=$this->db->get();
      return $query4->result();   
      return $query4->num_rows();

   }
   ```